# IPTV: Multicasting over Internet

Tags: bandwidth

is it possible to multicast over internet? I think IGMP is not allowed by the ISPs, and also when the server sends stream to internet what is the upload bandwidth on the server side? thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to multicast over the internet certainly but by far the best way is if you have control of every piece between your servers and clients. I work for a company that has that control for around 30-40% of the country's ADSL links so have the option of using multicast - that's a luxury that not eveyone has. Oh and you can't predict the upload bandwidth from clients, you have to engineer that.

Answer (score 0):

multicast over public internet will not work. you have choice of CDN with plenty of mirrors or using p2p-like approach where your clients become also relay nodes [ this will introduce additional latency, if you want to sort-of-multicast a movie - this works great - for instance [voddler](http://voddler.com/) uses such approach where clients become 'seeding' nodes for other clients - this allows content provider to save distribution costs ].